# Gather JAR files from dependencies in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have project A that has dependencies on external jars. It compiles fine, I can upload its jar file into an Ivy repository as 'group:A:1.0'. Ivy.xml shows the right external dependencies.

I then have project B, which has a compile dependency 'group:A:1.0' (i.e. not the local project, but the remote artifact)

I want to be able to copy all the jar files that A depends on, all those that B depends on, and put them all in a folder.

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from(project.configurations.runtime) 
    into project.file(project.ext.myDir)
}

The problem I'm running into is that only the jars that B depend on get found (including A). How do I get the jars A depend on.

Comment: Have you looked into the gradle application plugin? The packaging tasks from the application plugin should collect all required dependencies (transitive and otherwise) to create a locally executable package.

Comment: Ah! thank you! Perfect